# Why is cp_gullywash on the Attack/Defense mappool instead of Control Points mappool?

Tags: team-fortress-2

On the Attack/Defense playlist, there's a map called Gullywash. However, it has a control points format rather than an attack/defense format. Why is it on the attack/defense mappool rather than the control points mappool?

Comment: Was this on an official server or found though the play multiplayer menu?

Comment: @Studoku It's a common map on official servers that are under the attack/defense gamemode

Comment: When did this happen? According to the changelog this was the case but was fixed in March 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Gullywash was added, it was accidentally put in the wrong map list because both Attack/Defense and Control Point maps use the format "cp_mapname".

This was, according to the changelog, fixed in updates in February and March 2013. If it's still happening, contact Valve.

Comment: I still see it when I click "show servers" for attack/defense, but it doesn't bother me. I was just curious. Thanks for the answer however :)